# Multiple DataTriggers in Style with Bindings

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, triggers

I have a Grid with some animations:

```
<Grid.Style>
    <Style>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=PanelShown}" Value="True">
                <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                    <BeginStoryboard>
                        <Storyboard>
                            <ThicknessAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Margin" Duration="0:0:0.2" To="0,-350,0,350" />
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                <DataTrigger.ExitActions>
                    <BeginStoryboard>
                        <Storyboard>
                            <ThicknessAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Margin" Duration="0:0:0.2" To="0,0,0,0" />
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </DataTrigger.ExitActions>
            </DataTrigger>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=ReportErrorPanelShown}" Value="True">
                <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                    <BeginStoryboard>
                        <Storyboard>
                            <ThicknessAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Margin" Duration="0:0:0.2" To="-750,0,750,0" />
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                <DataTrigger.ExitActions>
                    <BeginStoryboard>
                        <Storyboard>
                            <ThicknessAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Margin" Duration="0:0:0.2" To="0,0,0,0" />
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </DataTrigger.ExitActions>
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</Grid.Style>
```

But this code doesn't works properly. If I remove one of the datatriggers it's working but if I just use this code only the second dataTrigger will trigger if the Binding property changes. How can I use two (or even more) DataTriggers with Bindings?

Comment: If you keep both DataTriggers, but reverse the order in which they are defined (such that the first shall be last, and the last shall be first) do you find that it is still the *second* one which seems to apply?

Comment: I just reversed the order and still only the second one seems to be applied.

Comment: Are `ReportErrorPanelShown` and `PanelShown` both true at once? The `Margin` property can have only one value at any given moment.

Comment: No they can't be both true at the same time. Either one of them is true and the other one is false or the way around.

Comment: Can you share the code which guarantees that?

Comment: Unfortunately you have to trust me as I'm not allowed to share this code. But I just debugged it and checked the values.

Comment: What you're describing is perfectly consistent with both properties being true at the time the triggers fire. The code you've shown will work if they aren't both simultaneously true; it's very simple and clear. Try putting in Setters for different properties: Maybe set BorderBrush in the first trigger and Background in the other, or some such. Just any two setters that can't step on each other.

Comment: I just changed the second Aniation to a DoubleAnimation modifiying the width and it works fine. But I just checked it once more: The values are not both true at the sime time.

Comment: Do I correctly understand that when you change the second animation to a DoubleAnimation on the width, the first animation starts to take effect?

Comment: And you've confirmed that PropertyChanged is being raised correctly every time either of the properties changes?

Comment: Yes and yes. The property is definetly raised as other elements are also changing if the property changes.

Comment: The only remaining unknown for me is the exact point in time at which you're eyeballing the watch window. UPDATE: Well, I shouldn't quite go that far. But there's not a lot left.

Comment: Well I don't exactly know what you mean

Comment: It sounds like you're telling me that when you have the triggers animating different properties, it's apparent that they're both executing. If that's the case, there is no point at which the first condition is true and the second is not.

Comment: They can't be both true as they are opening different panels. If they were both true both panels were open which is not possible as a panel can't be opened in my case when a panel is already opened because they are overlying the buttons which are opening the panels.